# Search terms separated by slash (as path segments) or separated by dash?

Tags: seo

Should I slugfy search terms together like `cars/san-francisco-california-blue-ferrari` or is it better to keep search terms as path segments like: `cars/california/san-francisco/blue-ferrari`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm really sorry, I did not know about webmasters.stackexchange.com. Can it be moved there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is probably more of a question for webmasters.stackexchange.com

That said, SEO is not the ultimate purpose of any website. First of all, you should look at making the site usable. If you can combine both that's perfect, but sometimes you have to make choices.

Slashes in a URL generally denote folders, or at least some kind of hierarchical structure. An url like www.mywebsite.com/my/personal/page/ gives off the impression that 'page' is a subset of 'personal' (whatever that may be within the context of my website), which itself is a subset of 'my'.

However, '/my-personal-page/' clearly shows a user that this is a page on the main level, where the foldername indicates that this actually is my personal page.

Whether or not slashes are better for SEO than dashes does not really matter in this case, as long as you make sure to provide your users a clear and easy understanding of your website structure.

Additionally, but I don't have any sources at hand to back this up so you may disregard it, I think that Google and others use the directory structure in the URL to roughly understand your site's structure as well, just like a visitor would.

I can't tell from your URL which part should or could be a folder, and which should or couldn't. You'll have to make up your own mind about that.

Edit:

Short answer: it depends on your website's structure.

Comment: I'll definitely have pages like 'show all cars for sale in San Francisco'. So I think slashes are the way to go in my case.

Comment: Yep. Another guideline is to match your url structure with your breadcrumb trail (if any). If you'd have Home > Cars > California > San Francisco as breadcrumbs, it's safe to add slashes on those places as well.